# SSRS 2019 Shared Schedules Expire Before Expiration Date

Tags: reporting-services

We have several shared schedules on an SSRS 2019 server that keep failing.  I have tried removing the end date and changing the end date to different dates in the future.

We have found scripts that show us the scheduled job ID so we can look at the job on the server.

What else should we be doing to help find the cause of this?

I'm not sure if this error is related.  The job ran this morning at 6am and expired some time after (but I don't know how to tell exactly when).  For the error related to the user account, this user has access to the report and is active.

library!ReportServer_0-1!11f0!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: i INFO: Entering StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = StyleSheet
library!ReportServer_0-1!11f0!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: i INFO: Exiting StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = StyleSheet (success)
library!ReportServer_0-1!4014!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;
session!ReportServer_0-1!4014!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: e ERROR: Error in getting session data: Invalid or Expired Session: 3js___Redacted____
session!ReportServer_0-1!4014!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: i INFO: LoadSnapshot: Item with session: 3js___Redacted____, reportPath: , userName: GHS2000\username_redacted_for_post not found in the database
library!ReportServer_0-1!4014!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ExecutionNotFoundException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ExecutionNotFoundException: The report execution 3js___Redacted____ has expired or cannot be found.;
library!ReportServer_0-1!4014!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/Scheduled/Hospital Managers/Medication Barcoding Compliance/Medication Barcode Compliance). User: GHS2000\username_redacted_for_post.
library!ReportServer_0-1!4014!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;
session!ReportServer_0-1!4014!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: e ERROR: Error in getting session data: Invalid or Expired Session: 3js___Redacted____
session!ReportServer_0-1!4014!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: i INFO: LoadSnapshot: Item with session: 3js___Redacted____, reportPath: , userName: GHS2000\username_redacted_for_post not found in the database
library!ReportServer_0-1!4014!06/27/2022-07:30:33:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ExecutionNotFoundException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ExecutionNotFoundException: The report execution 3js___Redacted____ has expired or cannot be found.;

Comment: If the owner of the subscription is no longer with your organisation and their domain account is disabled the subscription will fail.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Thank you.  We recently set this server up and I set up the shared subscriptions (my account is still active).  I'm not sure if we're finding the error that is causing the subscriptions to expire.  I have posted it to the main body of this question.